# grants for views in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle 12C and have a view created in one of our schemas(x). This view pulls data from tables(t1,t2,t3,t4...) all of which are located in another schema(y).I want to give select grant to this view for a user however even after granting this , user is not able to access the view.

I also gave select with grant option on the tables to schema(x) and then gave select access to the view for the user, still does not work.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the actual error message rather than saying that something "does not work".  Ideally with a reproducible test case that demonstrates the problem.  From your description, that should be working so there may be something else going on.

Comment: Hello! If you want more explicit info on how to write your question to increase prompt useful feedback, consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Otherwise, it is difficult to understand the problem well enough to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how it goes.

Create a brand new user (to avoid possible privileges granted earlier):

```
SQL> create user mike identified by lion default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connected as `SCOTT`, I'm going to create a view (as join of its `EMP` and `DEPT` tables) and grant `select` privilege to newly created user `MIKE`:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create view v_emp_dept as
  2    select d.dname, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  3    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.

SQL> grant select on v_emp_dept to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now, connect as `mike` and select from Scott's view:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select * from scott.v_emp_dept;

DNAME          ENAME      JOB              SAL
-------------- ---------- --------- ----------
RESEARCH       SMITH      CLERK            800
SALES          ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
SALES          WARD       SALESMAN        1250
RESEARCH       JONES      MANAGER         2975
SALES          MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
SALES          BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER         2450
RESEARCH       SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
ACCOUNTING     KING       PRESIDENT       5000
SALES          TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
RESEARCH       ADAMS      CLERK           1100
SALES          JAMES      CLERK            950
RESEARCH       FORD       ANALYST         3000
ACCOUNTING     MILLER     CLERK           1300

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Works OK, right? So, what have you done wrong? You probably *forgot* to specify view owner's name, i.e.

```
select * from scott.v_emp_dept;
              ^^^^^^
              This!
```

---

If you want to avoid that, create a synonym: first acquire that privilege, then name the synonym as you want (it can, but doesn't have to have the same name as the original view):

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant create synonym to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> create synonym my_emp_dept for scott.v_emp_dept;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from my_emp_dept where rownum = 1;

DNAME          ENAME      JOB              SAL
-------------- ---------- --------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER         2450

SQL>
```